# How do I compute the agreement between two Pandas data frame columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas data frame:

```
t = pd.DataFrame({"u": ["S1", "S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2", "S5", "S5", "S5"],
                  "v": ["a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a"],
                  "w": ["x", "z", "x", "x", "y", "y", "z", "x", "y"]})
```

I want to compute the agreement between columns `v` and `w` (something like the classification accuracy), grouped by column `u`. However, the values `a` and `b` in column `v` correspond to the values `x` and `y` in column `w` (the value `z` does not correspond to any value). Therefore, I cannot just simply compare these two columns.

What I do is I manually set the values in columns `v` and `w` to `0` (`a` and `x`), `1` (`b` and `y`), and `2` (`z`):

```
t.loc[t["v"] == "a", "v"] = 0
t.loc[t["v"] == "b", "v"] = 1
t.loc[t["w"] == "x", "w"] = 0
t.loc[t["w"] == "y", "w"] = 1
t.loc[t["w"] == "z", "w"] = 2
```

Now I can compare the two columns, grouped by column `u`, like this:

```
t.groupby("u").agg(lambda x: np.mean(x["v"] == x["w"]))
```

This gives me the desired result, but I wonder if there is a simpler way to achieve the same thing.

Furthermore, my solution does not work if I want to compute `np.corrcoef` instead of `np.mean`, i.e.

```
t.groupby("u").agg(lambda x: np.corrcoef(x["v"], x["w"]))
```

gives me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically do what you tried if you convert 'v' and 'w' to numerical types first.  Either 'int' or 'float' is fine, but I'd go with float as you are going to be treating them like continuous variables so might as well be explicit about it.

```
t[['v','w']] = t[['v','w']].astype(float)
```

It doesn't matter for your mean calculation because you're just generating a boolean that pandas interprets as 0/1.  But for the correlation coeffient you need to provide numbers.  You also need to use `apply` rather than `agg` here:

```
t.groupby("u").apply(lambda x: np.corrcoef(x["v"], x["w"]))
```

But that gives you a lot of extra output (a 2x2 where a scalar is sufficient), so I'd use the pandas `corr` method here:

```
t.groupby('u')['v'].corr(t['w'])

u
S1    1.000000
S2    1.000000
S5    0.866025
```

Based on your description of the problem I'm not sure that a correlation coefficient of 1 for 'S1' and 'S2' is really what you want here, but based on your translation of letter variables to number variables, that's the correct result.

Comment: Thanks! You're right, the correlation coefficient is not really suitable for this type of problem (classification accuracy is probably a better measure since I want to assess the level of agreement between two variables). On a related note, I was wondering if my string/number conversion could somehow be avoided by using the new factor type in Pandas.

Comment: @cle1109 I don't know what the new factor type is.  Are you referring to categorical variables?

Comment: Yes, I was referring to categorical variables. I thought that if I assigned `a` and `x` level 0, `b` and `y` level 1 (and `z` level 2) recoding the strings into numbers wasn't necessary. Anyway, I'm happy with the proposed solution :-).